# How to perform safe Single Sign On (SSO) in an html iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, single-sign-on, saml-2.0

Currently, an IDP (IDentity Provider) often doesn't allow SSO through an Iframe for security reasons (through Javascript you could capture the login/password in the main page).

How could a SSO be performed through an IFRAME in a safe way? That is, how could the IDP create their own sandbox in the IFRAME to perform a safe SSO?

I was thinking about a Java applet, but that has poor mobile support and other issues, like JRE versions, rights, etc..
What more options are there?
(BTW: I am using SAML).